# Dependencies cannot be compiled in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, android-appcompat

When the `implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.0.0'` is added in build.gradle file, Error is shown on line number 24 while implementing appcompat:`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'`

[its the build.gradle(Module:app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrFKK.png)

[Error in Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xl0H.png)

Comment: All three answers below point to the same problem. Go to Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From your gradle error message, it is seen that your are using the **andorid** earlier project structure library.
- You are trying to implement `implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.0.0'` library which is using the **androidx** support library structure.

Hence, your are getting that error as you cannot use both the structure as they have been made and organized complete differently.

**Solution:**

Shift to **androidx** library structure if you really want to use that library.

Refer this official documentation of Google Android to migrate to andoirdx from android -

[Google Developers Documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: after migrating to androidx,there is an error:  please refer my todays question

Comment: Provide a link of your new question here to let me give the solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

The library you are trying to use is using AndroidX libraries and you are using Andeoid support libraries in your project. Either migrate your project to androidx or ise an older version of the library which use android support libraries.

Comment: after migrating to androidx,there is an error:  please refer my todays question

Answer (score 1):

You should migrate your project `AppCopact to AndroidX`. For migrating project AppCompact to Androidx Go `Refactor -> Migrate to Androidx` then tick on BackUp Project and Migrate. After Migration The `com.karumi:dexter:6.0.0` library will work perfectly.

Comment: after migrating to androidx,there is an error:  please refer my todays question